# How to get first visible DOM element currently showing on the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multiple-columns

How to get first visible DOM element currently showing on the screen ?

I tried something like

```
var el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y)
```

and increasing the `y` coordinates in a `while` loop, but the problem is it does not work when there are CSS multi columns on the document, in that case the `<html>` tag is returned, not the actual element.

Is there any way I can really get the element on the top-left of the screen which works for CSS columns?

Comment: Can't you do just that but check if tagName is body/html/(unwanted elements)

Comment: @apelsinapa I guess that is the only way. I just didn't want to make a while loop mess. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **very basic** example that just gets the element that is the furthest to the `top`. It's just a start, because you may want to take into consideration the `left` offset as well.

You'll want to exclude the `body` and `html` elements (as shown below), since they will always be first.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjsUq/)

```
var first;
$(':visible').not('body, html').each(function() {
    if (typeof first == 'undefined') {
        first = $(this);
    } else if ($(this).offset().top < first.offset().top) {
        first = $(this);
    }
});
first.addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: +1, with the caveat that if you care about the left too, you'll need to add that just like the top is checked here.

Comment: @Aaron Blenkush I think I will try this out and modify it to what I need. thanks

Comment: @CodeWeed, I just realized as well: this won't take into account the scrolled position of the window. If that is a factor, you'll need to take that into consideration (subtract the `window.scrollY` from the offsets). You may also need to consider the height of each element -- you may scroll so that an element is off the edge of the window, but the bottom portion may still be visible. In that case you'd *add* the height of the element back in to get the "position" of the bottom edge of the element in relation to the window. Then you'd just get the smallest value that's not less than zero.

Comment: @CodeWeed: Actually, if you needed to take into account scrolling, you'd most likely need to implement an "overlap" formula, to see if the element overlaps with the window at all AND is `:visible` AND is closest to the top left. Don't know how complicated you want to go with this!

Comment: @AaronBlenkush Thanks I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea, especially if you have many elements, is to do a binary search. Here is a complete example. The goal of this code is to highlight in a sidebar the headings of sections which are currently visible in `<main>`.

```js
const asideTocItems = Array.from(asideToc.querySelectorAll('li'))
    .map(item => ({ item: item, heading: document.getElementById(getItemTargetId(item)) })),
  mainBlock = document.querySelector('main');
function updateAsideToc() {
  // Binary search to find the first heading which is above the top
  let searchTop = 0, searchBot = asideTocItems.length;
  while (searchTop + 1 < searchBot) {
    const searchMid = (searchTop + searchBot) >> 1, heading = asideTocItems[searchMid].heading;
    if (heading.offsetTop - getElemFontSize(heading) <= mainBlock.scrollTop) {
      searchTop = searchMid;
    } else {
      searchBot = searchMid;
    }
  }
  // Previously marked items are unmarked
  for (const item of asideToc.querySelectorAll('li.current')) {
    item.classList.remove('current');
  }
  // We mark items starting from the found one
  const visibleBottomY = mainBlock.scrollTop + mainBlock.clientHeight;
  for (let itemNum = searchTop; itemNum < asideTocItems.length; ++itemNum) {
    // If the current heading is below the bottom, it’s time to leave
    const heading = asideTocItems[itemNum].heading;
    if (heading.offsetTop + getElemFontSize(heading) >= visibleBottomY) {
      break;
    }
    let item = asideTocItems[itemNum].item;
    item.classList.add('current');
    // Parents are expanded
    do {
      item.classList.remove('collapsed');
    } while ((item = item.parentElement.closest('li')) != null);
  }
  // Previously expanded items are collapsed back, unless they still have current items
  for (const item of asideToc.querySelectorAll('.hasChild:not(.current):not(.collapsed)')) {
    if (item.querySelector('.current') == null) {
      item.classList.add('collapsed');
    }
  }
  // We scroll the sidebar so that all marked items are visible
  const currentItems = asideToc.querySelectorAll('.current > a');
  if (currentItems.length > 0) {
    const first = currentItems[0], last = currentItems[currentItems.length - 1],
      container = asideToc.closest('aside');
    if (first.offsetTop < container.scrollTop) {
      container.scrollTop = first.offsetTop;
    } else if (last.offsetTop + last.offsetHeight > container.scrollTop + container.clientHeight) {
      container.scrollTop = last.offsetTop + last.offsetHeight - container.clientHeight;
    }
  }
}
mainBlock.onscroll = updateAsideToc;
updateAsideToc();
```

It is for the HTML manual of a program of my teacher. It is currently live [here](https://sylvain-chiron.emi.u-bordeaux.fr/gengraph.html) but should be moved [here](https://dept-info.labri.fr/%7Egavoille/gengraph.html) soon.

I may miss some interesting or more optimized features of JavaScript. It is so complicated…!

As it is a common feature on websites, I am curious to know if they use that same technique or if they have a better (or worse?) one.