# How to get first visible body element (on screen) with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Someone knows how to reference the "nearest to the top" dom element currently on visible screen?

Something like this solution:
[How to get first visible DOM element currently showing on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415242/how-to-get-first-visible-dom-element-currently-showing-on-the-screen)
; but purely on javascript.

Don't care about position coords, nor anything else, than just get reference to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The linked question uses JavaScript, what do you mean "purely in JavaScript"?

Comment: probably mean without jQuery

Comment: Is this something that needs to be calculated frequently (on scroll, for instance)? If so, you might find [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) useful.

Comment: @amn I mean, no libraries involved (E.g. jQuery

Comment: @spender Rite. That's why I pointed "element currently on visible screen". Thaks for your note!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the same code as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15415501/7448536) but without jQuery.

```js
function visible(elem) {
  return !(elem.clientHeight === 0 || elem.clientWidth === 0)
}

let first;
let firstOffY;
let allVisible = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('body > *')).filter(visible)
for(const elem of allVisible) {
  //Calculaate the offset to the document 
  //See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18673641/7448536
  const offY = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop
  if (first == null || offY < firstOffY) {
    first = elem;
    firstOffY = offY;
  }
}

first.classList.add('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
</div>
```

- `document.querySelectorAll('body > *')` Select all elements under `body`
- `Array.from` Convert the return value of `querySelectorAll` to a real array
- `.filter(visible)` discard all elements that are not visible

Answer (score 1):

In case you need better compatibility, here a bit adjusted Wendelin's answer.

```js
function visible(elem) {
  return !(elem.clientHeight === 0 || elem.clientWidth === 0)
}

let first;
let firstOffY;
var elems = [], source = document.querySelectorAll('body > *');
for(var elemI=0;elemI<source.length;elemI++) {
   elems.push(source[elemI]);
}
let allVisible = elems.filter(visible)
for(var elem in allVisible) {
  elem = allVisible[elem];
  //Calculaate the offset to the document 
  //See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18673641/7448536
  const offY = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop
  if (first == null || offY < firstOffY) {
    first = elem;
    firstOffY = offY;
  }
} 

console.log(first.outerHTML);
first.classList.add('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Really appreciate it!!